# Excel - using lookup functions with more than one lookup value

Tags: excel

I have a document which has a list of agency numbers.

I know commpany X has 4 different agency numbers, for example: 111,222,333,444. I want to search the document and if it hits a match of 111, 222,333 or 444 I want it to return "company X" - I can do this using IF statements but there are many companies and I want a more efficient way of doing it

example of if statement:

=IF(OR(K2=111,K2=222,K2=333,K2=444),"company X", "other")

Comment: Please show the code you have so far.

Comment: It is still unclear what you are asking. What does your document look like? How do you know which agency numbers the companies have?

Comment: It is a list of agency numbers, I know which agency number corresponds to which company but some companies have multiple agency numbers - I want to match the agency number with my document and return the name of the company.

Comment: Is the list of agency numbers in one cell with commas between them or in separate cells?

Comment: HOW do you know which agency number corresponds to which company? Have you memorized it or do you have a list? Is the list in the same document? Also, please clearify what you mean by "match the agency number with my document". The documents filename? Some text in the document? It is not clear what you are working with and what result you expect other than "return company name". Return it to what? to a cell? To another document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you should use the VLOOKUP function (or one of the other LOOKUP functions). To make it work, you would need a separate table that lists all your companies associated with their numbers, e.g.

```
    [A]    [B]
[1] 1111   Company X
[2] 2222   Company X
[3] 3333   Company X
[4] 4444   Company X
[5] 5555   Company AA
[6] 6666   Company BBB
(etc)
```

I assume for the example this is on `Sheet2`. Your lookup statement would look something like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(K2, Sheet2!A:B, 2, FALSE)
```

The help on the function wizard (or the documentation) will explain the arguments in more detail and help you fine-tune them to your particular circumstances.